# How to load json file with multiple fields to dataframe based on few repetitive values in python?

Tags: python, json, pandas, pyspark, data-analysis

Is there an easy way to load json file with the following structure:

```
('ID_1', 'col1_1', 'col2_1' col3_1', 'key1', 'value1', 'col6_1')
('ID_1', 'col1_1', 'col2_1' col3_1', 'key2', 'value2', 'col6_1')
('ID_1', 'col1_1', 'col2_1' col3_1', 'key3', 'value3', 'col6_1')
('ID_2', 'col1_2', 'col2_2' col3_2', 'key1', 'value1', 'col6_2')
('ID_2', 'col1_2', 'col2_2' col3_2', 'key2', 'value2', 'col6_2')
('ID_2', 'col1_2', 'col2_2' col3_2', 'key3', 'value3', 'col6_2')
```

to achieve:

```
('ID_1', 'col1_1', 'col2_1' col3_1', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3', col6_1')
('ID_2', 'col1_2', 'col2_2' col3_2', 'key1', 'key2', 'key3', col6_2')
```

and value1, value2, value3 assigned to key1, key2, key3 accordingly?

I would like to use pandas or pyspark functions.

Comment: Those are not valid JSON or dataframe structures...

Comment: Your sample is not a valid JSON structure.

Answer (score 0):

This file structure  is an invalid JSON file but you can use `DataFrame.drop_duplicates()` to drop duplicates:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'brand': ['Yum Yum', 'Yum Yum', 'Indomie', 'Indomie', 'Indomie'],
    'style': ['cup', 'cup', 'cup', 'pack', 'pack'],
    'rating': [4, 4, 3.5, 15, 5]
})

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['brand'], keep='first', inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

[API Reference](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to keep all 'key' 'value' columns and convert it to proper structure. When dropping duplicates from df I loose those data. I am thinking about creating 2 smaller dataframes, removing duplicates from the first one and from the second create a pivot table and then merge it together?

Comment: yeah, you may want to do it like that, but I'm not an expert at pandas so I recommend to do some research on that on your own too